# amplify - deployment not triggering after new merge

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-amplify

I've set-up a `main` branch in Amplify frontend.
Every time I have made changes on main branch, it should auto deploy a new version of frontend.

Everything works fine until today.
After I've merged `dev` branch to `main` branch in Github, I go to Amplify and find that the pineline is not running

It shows

```
Last commit: Merge pull request #230
```

But the latest one should be `#232`

How do I fix/debug it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to re-connect repository as many developers suggest through the Internet, but it doesn't work for me.

Finally, I've created a webhook in Amplify so that I can trigger the deployment manually

Comment: had to do the same but how will this be a CI then? need a better fix...

Comment: could you please share how have you complete this task?

Comment: ok...I've sen just pressing create webhook button it auto-generates a CURL http call :)

Answer (score -1):

In case there are others who don't know how to trigger a manual build with latest code... Today I found that it's possible to create a webhook and manually trigger a build. While this issue is being investigated, the webhook can be used as a workaround.

`Amplify Console → Build settings → Incoming Webhooks → Create Webhook.`

Then it's possible to use the curl command to trigger a new build.

Credit: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/400#issuecomment-582772160